# How to merge 3 dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have 3 datasets: restaurants.csv, users.csv and rating.csv. Restaurants.csv contains the restaurant ids and some features. Users.csv contains user ids and some user features. Raiting.csv contains restaurant ids, user ids and correspondig ratings.

`place_id feature1 feature2
     1        ..       ..

     2        ..       ..`

`user_id feature1 feature2
     1        ..       ..

     2        ..       ..`

`place_id user_id raiting
     1        1        2

     2        1        3`

I want to merge these 3 files to get one dataset which contains restaurants, users features and corresponding ratings as a label. I would like to get the dataset as follows:

`place_id  user_id place_feature1 ... user_feature2 raiting
     1        1       ..                                 2

     2        2       ..                                 3`

How can I do it?

Comment: Please can you share parts of your input dataframes and your desired output. In other words, a *[mcve]*. This way we can make sure that a solution we provide works for you.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need double [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

**Sample DataFrames**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'place_id':[1,2,3,4],
                   'B':[4,5,4,7],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4]})

print (df1)
   B  C  place_id
0  4  7         1
1  5  8         2
2  4  9         3
3  7  4         4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,3,4],
                   'D':[40,50,40,70],
                   'E':[70,80,90,40]})

print (df2)
    D   E  user_id
0  40  70        1
1  50  80        2
2  40  90        3
3  70  40        4

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,3,4,1,2],
                   'place_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2],
                   'rating':[7,8,9,4,4,5]})

print (df3)
   place_id  rating  user_id
0         1       7        1
1         1       8        2
2         1       9        3
3         1       4        4
4         2       4        1
5         2       5        2
```

---

For real data use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#df1 = pd.read_csv('restaurants.csv')
#df2 = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
#df3 = pd.read_csv('rating.csv')

df = df3.merge(df1, on='place_id', how='left').merge(df2, on='user_id', how='left')
print (df)
   place_id  rating  user_id  B  C   D   E
0         1       7        1  4  7  40  70
1         1       8        2  4  7  50  80
2         1       9        3  4  7  40  90
3         1       4        4  4  7  70  40
4         2       4        1  5  8  40  70
5         2       5        2  5  8  50  80
```